# Looking for words in a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
   Word                         Date
   paper pen                    03/02/2020
   pen                          03/02/2020
   salt                         03/03/2020
   Batch traditional loaf       03/04/2020
   Hi-fibre                     03/08/2020
   The pen is on the table      03/11/2020
   I went to the gym            03/10/2020
```

and its subset

```
            Num   Date
03/02/2020  43    03/02/2020
03/03/2020  12    03/03/2020
03/16/2020  32    03/16/2020
03/08/2020  42    03/08/2020
03/10/2020  21    03/10/2020
```

I would like to create a function which loops over `Date` in the subset in order to extract rows which have `Word` values containing `pen` in the original dataset.

To look for strings I using this:

```
df[df[['Date','Word']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('pen'))]
```

where `df` is the original dataset.
However I do not know how to loop over Date in the subset (`sub`) to get rows containing `pen` in `df`.

My expected output, looking for the dates below in df:

```
    03/02/2020
    03/03/2020  
    03/16/2020  
    03/08/2020
    03/10/2020
```

would be

```
   Word                         Date
   paper pen                    03/02/2020
   pen                          03/02/2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if `word` contains `pen` and check if `Date` [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) the list of `Date` from `subset`.
- [Pandas: Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data)

```py
df[df.word.str.contains('pen') & (df.Date.isin(subset.Date.unique().tolist()))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on loops over `dates` is possible, but not recommended.
However if loop is needed for some reasons then try:

dataframe `df`:

```
                      Word        Date
0                paper pen  03/02/2020
1                      pen  03/02/2020
2                     salt  03/03/2020
3   Batch traditional loaf  03/04/2020
4                 Hi-fibre  03/08/2020
5  The pen is on the table  03/11/2020
6        I went to the gym  03/10/2020
```

dataframe `dates`:

```
         date
0  03/02/2020
1  03/03/2020
2  03/16/2020
3  03/08/2020
4  03/10/2020
```

code:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame()
for d in dates.date:
    for w in df.loc[df.Date==d, 'Word'].values:
        if 'pen' in w:
            df_out = df_out.append(pd.DataFrame({'Word':w, 'Date':d}, index = [d]))
```

result `df_out.reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
        Word        Date
0  paper pen  03/02/2020
1        pen  03/02/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Is <del>your `Date`</del> any data unique? If so, you can use Panda's [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function to extract all values in your `Word` column onto your subset. Using the function you wrote to extract "pen", you should be able to get your desired results.

Ex)

```
new_sub = pd.merge(sub, df, on="Date", how="left")
new_sub[new_sub[["Date", "Word"]].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('pen'))]
```

If you don't have a unique identifier, you won't be able to do this. You can create one, attach it to `df` and pass it on to `sub` when you create it. Instead of joining by `Data` as I have above in code you join by unique ID.

Comment: Hi Kevin. II got this error: ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of join instead of merge. Fixed my code. Try now!

Comment: np. Now I am getting however this error: `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument` (on left)